# SnapChat Like Camera Button in FLutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Helllo Guys , I want to record a video with Zoom In and Zoom out during Recording Just Like SnapChat in FLutter . But didn't find any Solution.
AnyOne here help me out of this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve result by using **gesture detector**

```html
OutlineButton(
            onTap: () => getPicture(),
            onLongPress: () => getVideo(),
            child: Text('Long press to take video'),
        ),
```

Comment: @Amil Silawat how can i set a limit video for 10 sec and also how can i red border increase with the increasing a time of video just like snapChat